# Detailed change history of .NET framework versions?

Tags: .net, changelog

I am looking for a detailed change history (including bugfixes) of all .NET framework versions, especially the changes between 2.0 and 3.5 SP1.

I know that something like that exists for [v2.0 and v1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(VS.85).aspx), and for [v4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx). However, I could not find a history for v3.0 and v3.5/SP1.

**Background:** (slightly edited) We are having issues somewhere between deserialization of some XML data (using XmlReader) and the display of the data in the UI. These problems appear when we use .NET 3.5 SP1, but we did not have them in v2.0. Now, I would like to know if this is related to some change/bugfix in the framework, or if this is related to some other difference. Unfortunately, we do not have the source code of that piece of software, and most of the software is written using native C++/MFC, except for the deserialization part which is .NET.

Comment: It may be more useful to instead ask how to solve the problem you're seeing since moving from v2 to v3.5

Comment: The problem is: we do not know the problem. The effect is pretty strange and specific to the application, and there is a lot of stuff going on after the deserialization, so I do not think that any details about the problem would help to find a solution. Furthermore, there are good chances that the problem is somewhere else in the code. It is a pretty old and small piece of software that we do not have the source code of. I know this should not happen, but it *did* happen. And now we would like to see whether the problem might actually be caused by v3.5, or if it is something else.

Comment: Even worse, most of the code is native C++/MFC, and only the deserialization is .NET -- please do not ask why; it was not me who wrote that software. So we do not know what is actually going on between deserialization and display of the data. We only know that the displayed data now differs from the data that was displayed when using .NET v2.0. Any details about what is displayed would not help any of you, trust me. :)

Comment: 3.0 is here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822048.aspx and 3.5 is here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332048(VS.90).aspx - don't see any changes relating to XML or serialization though.

Comment: @Mr Roys: Thanks for the links. That is what I was looking for. However, I would love to have a more detailed history, but I suppose this only exists MS internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some invfestigaion on my Dev box, here's what I found:

I have the following .NET Frameworks installed

- Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1
- Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SP2
- Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SP2
- Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

`XMLReader` is located in **System.XML.dll**

System.XML.dll is only found in two places:
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

I verified this by loading the 3.5 Framework into .NET Reflector and searching for `XMLReader`, it was referencing the 2.0 System.XML.dll.

This leads me to believe that this hasn't changed between v2.0 and v3.5 SP1.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation! This is interesting. I did not think of this solution. However, it might still be that there were other changes outside of System.XML.dll which might have an effect on our scenario. But I think it might be hard to find such changes. Maybe we should actually find another bug finding strategy... :)

Comment: @Gehho no problem. I guess the point I'm trying to make is that the problem is **most likely** not with XmlReader as your question suggests. I doubt there's any Linq involved as you say it worked on v2.0?

Comment: Yeah, maybe my question was misleading (now edited). We do not actually have problems with XmlReader, but somewhere between deserialization and display of the data. I *supposed* that it was XmlReader because this is almost the only .NET class that is used. But of course, it could also be that the source of the problem is something completely different (not even related to .NET). BTW: I will consider to accept your answer later if I do not get any better answers.

Comment: @Gehho The only other thing I can suggest is to use .NET Reflector in the .NET portion of the code you have available, maybe that'll give you better insight.

Comment: We already did that and did not find any suspicious code fragment. However, we found out what we now know about the code, i.e. it uses XmlReader + the only .NET portion of the software is deserialization. Anyway, thanks a lot for your effort!